# Tag for status change alerts in Outlook 2016/Skype for Business no longer works

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, microsoft-outlook-2016, skype-for-business

My employer uses Outlook/Exchange and Skype for Business.  I can open a user's contact card, click on the ellipses next to the Add and choose ***Tag for status change alerts*** This used to work great.  When a user's status would change from busy to available I would get a message box that would appear.

I can still turn on the notifications, but I don't see them any longer.  Is this something that my Exchange admin has turned off?  I would expect the option would be greyed out as well.

Thanks

Comment: What Outlook version are you using? Can you perform an update on your own to make sure its up to date to avoid that there is a bug which is already fixed via an update?

Comment: I was using Outlook 16.0.7341.2035.  I did an update using instructions [here](https://windowsinstructed.com/update-microsoft-office-2016-manually/) and it seemed to fix it!  I'm now at 16.0.8625.2121.  I also got the ability to add links to Skype for Business messages now.  Woo hoo!

Comment: Yes I expected that, there is a known bug which was solved with a latest SfB / Outlook version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written in the comment it looks like you are running an older Office / Skype for Business (SfB) version. There is a known bug which caused that the feature isn´t working as expected. So please make sure that Office and SfB is up to date. Then please try it again.